# Annotation information of method reference of an interface

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8, annotations

I want to extract annotation info of a method reference of interface like this:

```
giveMeAnnotaions(ControllerInterface::get)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Think about how you would declare such a method. The method passed in can be of any signature. What functional interface are you going to use so that it accepts all signatures? There is no such functional interface.

Even if you say "I'll just accept one kind of signature", you still can't do it. Whichever functional interface you use, you cannot "see" what the functional interface does. It's like a black box, accepting your inputs and splitting out some output. You don't know what's inside at runtime.

To write a method that returns a method's annotations, you must have a `Method` object, which can be acquired from a `Class<T>`, `String` and an array of `Class` for the parameter types:

```
public static Annotation[] getAnnotations(Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Class<?>... parameterTypes) throws ...
```